# Split text field on json

Tags: string, python-2.7

I want to do some data analysis on a json file generated from twitter.
The field that I need is the text field which contain the tweet itself.

your contribution is highly appreciated

```
 while tweetCount < maxTweets:
     try:
         if (max_id <= 0):
             if (not sinceId):
                 new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size)
             else:
                 new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, since_id=sinceId)

         else:
             if (not sinceId):
                 new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, max_id=str(max_id - 1))
             else:
                 new_tweets = api.search(q=search_query, count=tw_block_size, max_id=str(max_id - 1), since_id=sinceId)

         if not new_tweets:
             print("Collecte terminee.")
             break
         for tweet in new_tweets:
             day = tweet.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
             with open( "%s/%s_tweets.json" % (output_dir, day), 'a') as f:
                 f.write(json.dumps(tweet._json))
                 f.write('\n')
         tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
         print("{0} tweets téléchargés".format(tweetCount))
         max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
     except tweepy.TweepError as e:
         print("an error was occured to continue , run the following command:")
         print("python collect.py -s {0} -o {1} -u {2}".format(search_query, output_dir, max_id))
         print("")
         print("Error : " + str(e))
         break
```

Comment: what is your question? do you get an error somewhere?

Comment: There is no error , in the previous script the only improvment I still need is to split the tweet "text" itself word by word